# How to select Incremental custom tags in XML

Tags: javascript, xml

How do I select custom but incremental tags in XML and assign it to an Array? The number of paragraph tags varies on each page. Below JS code does not work
JS

```
for (i = 0; i <8; i++) { 
        var para[i] = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paragraph"[i])[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;   
    }

<paragraph1>Text</paragraph1>
<paragraph2>Text</paragraph2>
<paragraph3>Text</paragraph3>
<paragraph4>Text</paragraph4>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML has a number of APIs one can use to search the tree. Below I'm using [`evaluate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/evaluate) so that I can use [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/), a language built for navigating XML. I then iterate over the result and push the values to the array.

This may be overkill for the simple task you've laid out, but XPath provides a number of features that make it easy to find stuff in XML.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var parser = new DOMParser();
  var xmlDoc = parser.parseFromString("<root><paragraph1>Test</paragraph1><paragraph2>Test</paragraph2><paragraph3>Test</paragraph3></root>", "application/xml");
  var paragraphs = xmlDoc.evaluate("//*[starts-with(local-name(.), 'paragraph')]", xmlDoc, null, XPathResult.ANY_TYPE, null);
  var paras = [];
  var paragraph = paragraphs.iterateNext();
  while (paragraph) {
    paras.push(paragraph.textContent);
    paragraph = paragraphs.iterateNext();
  }
  console.log(paras);
};
```

It should be noted that the above does not work in Internet Explorer.  See [this chart for the supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=evaluate) (which is to say, all browsers *except* Internet Explorer).

Comment: I am getting the following error "Object doesn't support property or method 'evaluate' "

Comment: You are perhaps running this code in Internet Explorer? Yeah, it doesn't work in that ancient browser. See [this chart for the supported browsers](https://caniuse.com/#search=evaluate).

Answer (score 0):

This could work

```
for (i = 0; i <8; i++) {
    var p = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paragraph" + i);
    var paras.push(p[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
}
```

Comment: Edited the answer.

Comment: In the end this worked:  
var paras = [];
 for (i = 1; i <8; i++) { 
  paras.push(xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("paragraph"+i)[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue); 
 }